# How to run selenium in Docker with Flask?

Tags: python, django, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to run Selenium with Flask. The problem is that it throws an error.

```
[2022-12-16 11:30:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-12-16 11:30:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2022-12-16 11:30:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-12-16 11:30:05 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|██████████| 6.96M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 12.6MB/s]
[2022-12-16 11:30:07 +0000] [6] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrapeutil import get_db
  File "/scrapeutil.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/108.0.5359/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

What I've did:

1. Cross checkk if gunicorn is the culprit. I make a simple Dockerfile with only gunicorn and a flask endpoint that return "Hello World". It works as expected. Therefore, I assume that webdriver is the culprit.

The code that trigger the error

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

The Dockerfile

```
# Do not use Alpine Linux if you use pandas
# FROM python:3.10-alpine3.16
# bullseye https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /
# {module_import}:{app_variable}
# equivalent to 'from app import app'
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "app:app"]
```

The requirements.txt

```
flask==2.2.*
pandas==1.5.*
selenium==4.5.*
webdriver-manager==3.8.*
gunicorn==20.1.*
```

This code, in my Mac Mini M1 works. But when I tried to run the Docker Image, it throws the error.

Comment: Check chromedriver logs which has to be persisted within container

Comment: @AlexeyR. I am not sure how to do it. Is it because I need Google Chrome and Google Chrome binary? Everyone seems to `apt-get install google-chrome-stable` / do `wget to dl.google.com`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just take existing Selenium images?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Do you mean selenium-standalone-chrome docker image? I tried it and it throws error as well.

Comment: Yes, that image. I think you will more likely to get help with that one. Since there is much more people knowing how that image is built and would more likely advice what you're doing wrong rather than having your custom image.

Comment: @AlexeyR. Noted. I will create a new question.